# how to get the x and y position of a tiled map object with Libgdx?

Tags: java, libgdx, tiled

I've been searching around the internet for a while now and literally nothing has helped, but I've been trying to figure out how to get the x and y position of a Tiled map object.

I've tried using `map1.getLayers().get(3).getObjects().get(1).getX()` to get the x position but  the `getX()` method returns an error: Cannot resolve method 'getX' in 'MapObject'.

Is there another method I can use or should I just change my approach entirely?

Comment: What is the error that the `getX()` method returns?

Comment: Cannot resolve method 'getX' in 'MapObject', which I don't get seeing that it's worked with something similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map1.getLayers().get(3).getObjects().get(1)` will return a [MapObject](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/maps/MapObject.html), that doesn't define a `getX()` method. Depending on the type of the `MapObject` you need to cast it, to get it's position. E.g. if it's a [RectangleMapObject](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/maps/objects/RectangleMapObject.html) you can do this:

```
MapObject mapObject = map1.getLayers().get(3).getObjects().get(1);
if (mapObject instanceof RectangleMapObject) {
  RectangleMapObject rectangleMapObject = (RectangleMapObject) mapObject;
  // now you can get the position of the rectangle like this:
  Rectangle rectangle = rectangleMapObject.getRectangle();
  float x = rectangle.getX();
  float y = rectangle.getY();
  // TODO maybe add width and hight ...
}
```

If it's no RectangleMapObject you need to check the other subclasse of [MapObject](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/maps/MapObject.html).